# How can I invoke InstalledAppDetails that is under com.android.settings?

Tags: android

I am trying to invoke InstalledAppDetails using the following code. I get the error message saying there is no such activity.

```
Intent intent = Intent.parseUri("dat=package:com.example.android.jetboy cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails", 0);
intent.setAction("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dds.test/com.dds.test.TestLayout}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=dat=package:com.example.android.jetboy cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails }

Answer (score 4):

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:com.example.android.jetboy")));
```

Comment: For some reason, I got some crash reports about this command, for example : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.google.android.gms flg=0x50088000 }
 How could it be?

Answer (score 3):

you should invoke like this:

```
ComponentName componetName = new ComponentName(
                        "com.android.settings",
                        "com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails");
                intent= new Intent();
                intent.setAction("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.plusub.diapersapp"));
                intent.setComponent(componetName);
```

Comment: Works, but how can we open permission page??

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same crash when I used

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
startActivity(intent, null)
```

in Kotlin.

Avoided the crash by the following code:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: btw, if you just instantiate `Intent` like so:

`Intent(ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
           Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null))
`
it automatically sets the `intent.data`